# Search line in *.CSV-

Tags: c#, search, csv, streamreader

I can't belive, the easiest task won't work!

I just want to loop through a csv file by using the StreamReader-Class and find a key in a associative line. 
e.g.:

1. key1;value1
2. key2;value2
3. key3;value3

If the key exists, no problems. Otherwise EOF should be reached, but it does not work!

If I discard the buffered data, EOF will be reached everytime. In result no key will be found.

**Edit:** with all the suggestions, but same result!

```
StreamReader reader = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    try
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(@"ident.csv", Encoding.ASCII);
        string buffer;
        string[] str = null;

        while((buffer = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(buffer.Contains(";"))
            {
                str = buffer.Split(';');
                if(str[0].Equals(textBox1.Text))
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(reader == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ident not found!");
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = str[1];
            Clipboard.SetText(str[1]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Dispose();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Set ident!");
}
}
```

Comment: _How_ does it not work? I'm expecting a null-reference exception on `buffer.Contains()`, but why do we have to guess?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the str = buffer.Split(';'); line to see what you're actually getting from the file? If the split is failing it could be file encoding in your csv file as SmartJJ suggests

Comment: Regarding the Edit: You want to test `if(buffer == null)` (not reader). And You're still unclear about what is (not) happening. If English is a problem, at least post the output of the program.

Answer (score 0):

very strange, this works on my pc:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string buffer = string.Empty;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"e:\a.csv");
    do
    {
        buffer = reader.ReadLine();
        if (buffer.Contains(";"))
        {

            string[] str = buffer.Split(';');
            if (str[0] == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!reader.EndOfStream);
}
```

csv contains:

```
1;2;3;4;5;
sdfsdf;sdfsdfcv;aasd;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `StreamReader` be in a `using` statement or something? Or at least closed somehow...

Answer (score 0):

As Konerak points out in his comment, use .equals() to compare Strings.
It just happens that "1" == "1" AND "1".equals("1") both are true but it's just a coincidence (that's why the second piece of code works). More on String equality [here](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html).

Comment: Those are notes for string equality in Java. Isnt this C#?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget:the file coding is the key for read files!
coding:UTF8,ASCII,UTF16,GB2312

Answer (score 0):

Stupid thought but does either ident.csv or your textbox contain any extra spaces?

Try something like `if(str[0].Trim().Equals(textBox1.Text.Trim()))`